# Which Android APIs are supported in Flex Air?

Tags: android, apache-flex, api, air, air-android

Anyone know where I can find what Android APIs are supported in the latest Flex AIR SDK (Hero). In particular is the speech to Text API supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to focus less on "Hero" and focus on AIR for Android.  I would not expect there to be any Flex specific APIs that relate to AIR for Android.

You might want to start here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile_development_hero_burrito.html

I couldn't find a specific document detailing the AIR Android specific APIs for some reason.

I was unaware of any text to speech API supprt.  Is there an underlying API on that as part of the Android SDK?

Comment: Yes there is a speech to text api:   http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html  . So I was wondering if you could leverage it in a Adobe AIR app.....

Answer (score 2):

They made a "Tour d' Flex" for Android that shows you most of the APIs.  Speech to Text is not in the app, though.

http://www.jamesward.com/2010/10/26/tour-de-mobile-flex-now-available-for-android/